# In college sports, why is permission needed to recruit other coaches?

Tags: collegiate, coaching

It seems a big deal is made about athletic directors getting permission before recruiting other schools' coaches. Is this based on some rule or is it more of a professional courtesy? And under what conditions can permission be denied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the same factors are in play for both college and professional leagues. At the end of [this article](http://www.upi.com/Sports_News/2012/01/17/Bears-asst-coach-denied-interview/UPI-59411326814713/), the writer notes that:

> The only time a team is required to grant permission for assistants
>   who are under contract to interview with other teams is for head
>   coaching positions. Interviews for other types of positions are at the
>   discretion of team officials.

Schools may request permission to interview coaches for a few reasons:

- Professional courtesy: they'd want to have the same courtesy extended when other schools wish to speak with their coaches
- Some coaches may be under contract: in these cases, schools may permission to speak with coaches under contract to prevent breach of contract lawsuits

Note: The rule specified in the article above applies only to the NFL, which has additional rules governing the coaching interview process.